# Optimized Linq IEnumerable query

Tags: linq

I have a query which is enumerating over and over and taking very long to run. Can somebody help me optimized it.

```
 public EmpListItem(IEnumerable<EmployeeTable> Emps)
    {
        IEnumerable<EmployeeTable> emptable = Emps as EmployeeTable[] ?? Emps.ToArray();
        TeamList = emptable.Select(x => x.Surname
            .Select(c => new EmployeeListItem(c.EmployeeTables.Where(emptable.Contains)))
            .Where(x => x.EmpDtos.Any())
            .ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Please add some more context - what are you trying to do and how is this query doing it? Also: 1. Why are you forcing the input to an array? 2. Why are you (supposedly) iterating over the characters in the `Surname` value?

Comment: I have figured out my issue. Most of my Linq queries are using custom order by clauses causing performance issues. Also I realized that .any was also slowing the performance. Changing it to FirstOrDefault made a big difference. Thanks